# How to replace date parameters in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help please?
I have a column with values such as this: "SRK_ABC_%y%m%d_%H%H.txt"

In an sql select statement, how could I replace these with values from sysdate please?
Thanks.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post what the value should be after the replacements. By the way, shouldn't that be `%M` instead of the second `%H` ?

Comment: SRK, why 5 parameters? If that should be *sysdate*, why don't you use a single parameter? BTW, @Abra, %M would then "duplicate" %M which is used for month so that won't be good either.

Comment: @Littlefoot if you look closely, it appears that `%m` represents the month in the sample column value in the question.

Comment: Thank you guys as well. fyi, It is just the required format of the output files to the client. I have masked it with alternative characters .

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE` to substitute each of the components:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 'SRK_ABC_%y%m%d_%H%M.txt',
                 '%y',
                 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
               ),
               '%m',
               TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM')
             ),
             '%d',
             TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD')
           ),
           '%H',
           TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')
         ),
         '%M',
         TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MI')
       ) AS updated_filename
FROM   DUAL
```

If it always has the same format then (assuming `%M` rather than the second `%H`):

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
         'SRK_ABC_%y%m%d_%H%M.txt',
         '%y%m%d_%H%M',
         TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD_HH24MI')
       ) AS updated_filename
FROM   DUAL
```

Which both output:

> | UPDATED_FILENAME |
> | --- |
> | SRK_ABC_20210929_1226.txt |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=505b1dbd8a221029fa8d317c68c6e496)*

Comment: Thanks for you responses.
They are not in the same format, there a few different types, e.g.
XXXXX.%y%m%d%H%M%S, 
xxxxxx_dc.%y%m%d, 
xxxxxx_%y%m%d_01.dat

Can REGEXP_REPLACE function be utilised somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: @SRK If they are different formats then just use the first query. Why try to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` when `REPLACE` works? If you are asking whether it can be written with a single `REGEXP_REPLACE` function call then, no, as you have multiple different replacement values for each time component and regular expressions are not a magic bullet that you can throw in to solve this easily. (Maybe in other languages where you can pass a callback function instead of the replacement text but you cannot do that in SQL.)

Comment: Appreciated, MT0.
But, this sql will be embedded in an unix script but passing a parameter and hence I need a generic solution.

Comment: but I will give it a go with your first solution. thanks.